# Large array in C segfaults, Sievs of erathos

Tags: c, memory, stack

So, I've got this code.

```
void main(void){

    int n = 9999;
    int *array = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    int i, j;

    // Populate array up to N
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        array[i] = 2 + i;
    }

    // Run sievs
    sievs(array, n);

    print_prime(array, n);
}
```

My problem is that if N is sufficently large, the program will core dump. My theory is that something is allocated on the stack, and it is not large enough to hold that much data, however I am using calloc, so it should be on the heep.

The two print functions looks something like this:

```
void print_prime(int *a, int n){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(a[i] != -1)
            printf("Prime: %d \n", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Is any of this code causing it? I don't see why.

Here is the siev function:

```
void sievs(int *array, int n){

    int i, j;

    for(i = 2; i <= n; i++){
        if(array[i-2] != -1){
            for(j = i*i; j <= n; j+=i){
                array[j-2] = -1;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I can not see anything wrong, however, I'm only at my second year at computer science, so I'm not that experienced in C. I have tried to fix this for a while. It works fine with small numbers. However, not with large ones, and everything I've read on the internet states that it could be a problem with the stack.

Is anything here beeing allocated on the stack here?

Comment: You should run your code inside a debugger like `gdb` and see where the segfault occurs. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

Comment: I will remember that next time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The program will crash for `n` large enough because

```
j = i * i
```

will cause the `j` variable (of `int` type) to overflow.  Hence in

```
array[j-2] = -1;
```

the index `j - 2` will be negative.

You can fix the problem either by declaring `j` at least `long`, or by resorting to arbitrary precision libraries (such as [the GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/)).

Answer (score -3):

"i <= n" and "j<=n" have snuck into the "sievs()" function. They should be "i < n" and "j < n".

Comment: In the ```sievs``` function he accesses ```array[i-2]``` and ```array[j-2]```, so even if ```i``` or ```j``` is equal to n, it will not exceed the allocated memory.